# Двойные имена — как склонять?

Tags: склонение, ономастика

*Встреча с председателем Международной исламской благотворительной организации **Абдуллах Матуук Аль-Матууком.***

**Как склонять такое имя**:
1. Абдуллахом Матууком
2. Абдуллахом Матуук
3. Абдуллах Матуук.

**В каком справочнике дается ответ на этот вопрос?**

Как-то на сайте **"Корректор"** было такое:

Друзья, склоняется ли первая часть имени Нур Мухаммед Тараки?
Нур Мухаммеда Тараки или Нура Мухаммеда Тараки?

1. Мусульманские двойные имена обычно склоняют как единое имя. (Что это значит?)
2. Нет, склонять не надо. Это каприз орфографии, такие двойные имена раньше писали слитно.

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
Корректно:

Хассан Ахмад Хаммуда
кому?
Хассану Ахмаду Хаммуде.

Answer (score 0):

Увы, правил не приведу, лишь поясню данный Вами же ответ.

> Мусульманские двойные имена обычно склоняют как единое имя:
>   (т.е. меняется только окончание последней части имени/фамилии)

```
им.п.  - Абдуллах Матуук Аль-Матуук  
род.п. - Абдуллах Матуук Аль-Матуука  
дат.п. - Абдуллах Матуук Аль-Матууку  
вин.п. - Абдуллах Матуук Аль-Матуука  
тв.п.  - Абдуллах Матуук Аль-Матууком
пр.п.  - Абдуллах Матуук Аль-Матууке
```

Да, если сомневаетесь - всегда можно построить предложение так, чтобы не приходилось склонять имя. Получается немного косноязычно, но точно не ошибетесь (часто использую при общении непосредственно с человеком, чтобы не дай Бог не оскорбить):

```
На встрече, где присутствовал председатель Абдуллах Матуук Аль-Матуук, (...)
```

**UPD:** ниже в комментарии привел [ссылку](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/info/ag/sklon/) с описанием правила.

Comment: Я не согласен. А на основании чего мусульманским именам надо предоставлять какое-то исключение?

Comment: Имена собственные вообще очень сложно поддаются описанию правилами, насколько я помню из школьного курса. И с большим количеством исключений. [Вот здесь](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/info/ag/sklon/) про "восточные" имена:  **5.2.** _В составных именах и фамилиях вьетнамских, корейских, китайских и др. склоняется последняя часть._

Comment: Почему? Есть вполне осмысленный исчерпывающий набор правил. О нем спорят, обсуждают и корректируют... Но он есть. Просто не надо ограничиваться школьными знаниями.

Comment: http://www.gramota.ru/class/istiny/istiny_8_familii/  -  вот базовый набор "нешкольных" правил.

Answer (score 0):

Если мне память не изменяет, то "Нур" —  это не имя как таковое, а префикс-титул, поэтому он может не склоняться.
Кроме того, в разговорной речи односложные даже истинные имена имеют стойкую тенденцию не склоняться, если это имя известного лица, тесно связанное с фамилией ("читал Жюль Верна").

Поэтому рекомендация не склонять "Нур" объяснима, хотя и спорна. Но обобщать на имена типа Абдуллы никак нельзя.